# the depth of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The depth of a set X is the maximal number of nestings it contains. The definition runs as follows:

```
if X contains no set, depth(X) = 0
```

otherwise

```
depth(X) = max ({depth(Y)| Y ∈ X}) + 1,
```

(where max(M) is the maximal number of a set of integer numbers M). Given this definition, determine

```
(1) depth(S), S = {f, g}

(2) depth ({ {a}, {{{{a}}}}, {{a}} }

(3) depth (℘(℘(℘(℘(S)))))
```

hense I can consider that

```
(1) 0
(2) (1+4+2) +1 =8?
(3) 4+1 = 5?
```

Can please somebody explain? I did`t really get the idea

Answer (score 2):

Think about a set with the membership inclusion as some sort of a tree. The root is the set $X$. Leaves, or terminal nodes, of the tree are elements which are not sets.

The we want to ask what is the height of the tree, what is the length of the longest branch? That, in a nutshell, the idea of the depth. At least when concerning a universe of just finite sets (what happens if you take an infinite set which has sets of every possible finite depth? There's no $\max$ for the definition! Well, then we need ordinals, but I'm getting ahead of myself.

Note that the definition is not to *add* all the depths of sets in $X$ and then add $1$. It's to take the *maximal* depth, and add $1$. So in the case of $(2)$ the answer is not $8$, but rather $5$.

In the third answer you might want to prove something first, $\operatorname{depth}(\wp(S))=\operatorname{depth}(S)+1$, and then you can easily reiterate it to find out the correct answer.

Comment: then in 1) depth is equal 1 and 3) 4?

Comment: @user144257: Well, are $f$ and $g$ sets? If not, then $\{f,g\}$ is a set which contains no sets. In the fourth question, that depends on the depth of $S$.

Comment: yes right, just got cobfused. the first set contains no set so it should be still 0.
But about the last one...it`s still not clear.

Comment: Well, it's not clear what is the depth of $S$?

Comment: no, the depth of S should be 0 in (1) task

Comment: i didnt get the last one with the power set

Comment: I meant about the last one, with the power set. This is a repeated power set operation from *some* set $S$, do you know what this set is? What is its depth? In either way you can easily write it as a function of the depth of that $S$. If it's the same $S$ from the first part, then you already have the answer.